# ¿Cómo limitar las categorías a elegir en un custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Dentro de un `custom post type`, en la ventana lateral derecha de `selección de categorías`, justo aquí:

[image: selección de categorías]

En esa venta ¿es posible establecer cuales categorías se tienen que mostrar según el custom post type?

Por ejemplo, en cualquiera de mis CPT se muestran absolutamente todas las categorías que he creado, lo cual me hace ineficiente la labor de categorizar ciertas páginas que pertenecen a determinados CTP por la gran cantidad de categorías que se muestran, siendo que generalmente necesito usar una o dos entre casi 150 categorías y sigue creciendo...

Lo ideal en mi caso seria poder indicar cuales categorías se van a mostrar según el CPT en el que me encuentre, es decir, si estoy en el CPT de Películas, que se muestren categorias relacionadas a Películas solamente. Si voy al CPT de Juegos, entonces que se muestren las categorías relacionadas con juegos; y no absolutamente todas las categorías que estoy usando hasta el momento.

De ahí mi pregunta, ¿es posible establecer cuales categorías se tienen que mostrar según el custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible usando la función `register_taxonomy` pasando como argumento la taxonomía a crear y el post type al que quieres que se asigne la taxonomía, entonces tendrás un grupo de taxonomías personalizadas solo para un post type especifico, aunque es posible pasarle mas de un post type.

```
function taxonomia_personalizada {

    register_taxonomy('taxonomy_name', array('post_type'), array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'              => esc_html__('Nombre Taxonomia','theme'),
            'add_new_item'      => esc_html__('Agregar nueva categoria','theme'),
            'new_item_name'     => esc_html__('Agregar categoria','theme')
        ),
            'hierarchical'  => true,
            'query_var'     => true,
            'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'taxonomy-slug' )
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomia_personalizada', 0 );
```

Comment: excelente respuesta. Ahora un par de dudas. En mi caso ya tengo varias categorías creadas y a su vez esas categorías tienen subcategorías (o hijos). Ejm: Criaturas, sus hijos son Aves, Reptiles, Mamíferos. ¿Cual seria el modo correcto de añadirlas al código que mencionas? Mi duda es mas que todo por cómo integrar correctamente al padre con sus categorías hijas. Gracias!

Comment: En realidad lo que esta creando el código es una taxonomía, es decir, en tu post type en el área de categorías debería aparecer otro meta box con el nombre de tu taxonomía creada, es decir, otro cuadro igual al de categorías, ahí puedes crear las categorías y subcategorías pero pertenecientes a tu taxonomía personalizada. https://kinsta.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/what-is-a-taxonomy-3.png